# Ehcache cluster takes to long to startup on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ehcache

I am using a replicated ehcache which is deployed in Tomcat 7 environment. What happens here is that tomcat takes too long to startup with the logs getting filled up with ehcache heartbeat messages.

Any thoughts as to how we can speedup ehcache and Tomcat startup?

My ehcache.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true"> 

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/> 

    <transactionManagerLookup class="net.sf.ehcache.transaction.manager.DefaultTransactionManagerLookup"
                              properties="jndiName=java:/TransactionManager" propertySeparator=";"/> 
    <cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="com.adobe_services.cache.SampleCacheManagerEventListenerFactory" properties="type=counting"/>
  <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
            properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                        multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                        multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=1"
            propertySeparator=","
            />
    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
                                     properties="hostName=, port=, socketTimeoutMillis="/> 
     <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            statistics="false"
            />

    <cache name="replicatedCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="5"
           maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"
        propertySeparator="," />
    </cache>   

    <cache name="replicatedCache2"
    maxElementsInMemory="5"
           maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"
        propertySeparator="," />
    </cache>   


</ehcache>
```

Comment: can you post your ehcache config example?

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich - Updating the original question.

Comment: how about removing bootstrap loader from cache configuration?

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich - Would i face any issues if i remove bootstrap loader?

Comment: your cache will be empty when tomcat starts; bootstrap just tries to prefill it from other running nodes on start up

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich - Thanks for pointing to the direction. I changed the bootstrap to  asynchronous and that fixed the issue. Maybe you can add that as an answer. ( I would like to document it for posterity :))

Comment: @Apache Fan, added as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change bootstrapper strategy to be asynchronous (`bootstrapAsynchronously=true`) to avoid delays during start up i.e.:

```
<bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"
        propertySeparator="," />
```